# Creating a Repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, repository

I have been using 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
as guidance to help me create a repository.I have created a class with the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TheatreGroup.Models;

namespace TheatreGroup.DAL
{
    public interface IShowRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Show> GetShows();
        Show GetShowByID(int showId);
        void InsertShow(Show name);
        void DeleteShow(int showID);
        void UpdateShow(Show name);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

But when i come to create the second class i get an error saying:

> TheatreGroup.DAL.ShowRepository' does not implement interface member 'TheatreGroup.DAL.IShowRepository.InsertShow(TheatreGroup.Models.Show)'.

The error is on the 5line down (round about)

```
using System.Data;
using TheatreGroup.Models;

namespace TheatreGroup.DAL
{
    public class ShowRepository: IShowRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private TheatreContext context;

        public ShowRepository(TheatreContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Show> GetShows()
        {
            return context.Shows.ToList();
        }

        public Show GetShowByID(int id)
        {
            return context.Shows.Find(id);
        }

        public void InsertShows(Show name)
        {
            context.Shows.Add(name);
        }

        public void DeleteShow(int showID)
        {
            Show shows = context.Shows.Find(showID);
            context.Shows.Remove(shows);
        }

        public void UpdateShow(Show name)
        {
            context.Entry(name).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `InsertShows` not `InsertShow`. Your interface needs `InsertShow`.

Comment: +1 This should be a poster question for the benefits of pair-programming lol